# Unable to cast object to interface it implements - cast interface to another interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting, architecture

short description of my problem. I have passed generic object(interface) as parameter to my method. I need to call some method that will be common for subset of objects that implement  my interface. I do not want to "have if() then" for each type of object there. let's call the interface IVehicles.

```
public interface IVehicle 

{
    Object SomeValue { get;  }
}
public class Car : IVehicle{ //some code here}
```

It does not make sense to add method to IVehicle due to not sharing all logic.

I need to call SomePersonalValue only on subset of IVehicle. So I implemented another interface IPersonalVehicle and extended my objects:

```
public interface IPersonalVehicle 

{
    long SomePersonalValue { get;  }
}
public class Car : IVehicle, IPersonalVehicle {}
public class MotorBike : IVehicle, IPersonalVehicle {}
```

Now I have my method

```
public void Call(IVehicle vehicle)   
{
   Object someIrrelevantObject = vehicle.SomeValue;
   //here my change begins
   IPersonalVehicle personalVehicle = (IPersonalVehicle)vehicle; 
   long somePersonalValue = personalVehicle.SomePersonalValue;

}
```

the problem is that it raises Unable to cast object Car to interface IPersonalVehicle.I have also tried to extend my interface by IVehicles and the resilt is the same.

```
public interface IPersonalVehiclee : IVehiclee
{
    long SomePersonalValue { get;  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT - SOLVED** 
I forgot or somehow lost in code editation to to extend my Car and Motorbike by IPersonalVehicle lol, so this solution works! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Because there is not any relation between `IVehicle`  and `IPersonalVehicle`. 
You can declare `IPersonalVehicle` as `interface IPersonalVehicle : IVehicle` and it will allow you to cast down

Comment: Could you post a code that compiles? At the moment you have a typos such as `IVehicles` and `IVehicle`.

Comment: @ Sanan Fataliyev but in your suggestion I think I will need to extend all classes that implement IVehicle with method SomePersonalValue or am I wrong?

Comment: @Dennis typos fixed.

Comment: @SananFataliyev: it's OK to *guess*, that object that implements `IFoo` can implement `IBar` too. This code is legal both from the compiler and design points. This doesn't mean, that `IFoo` and `IBar` must be related somehow.

Comment: @Dennis, yes, you are right, i was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your question correctly, it works fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Call(new Car());

        Call(new MotorBike());
    }

    public static void Call(IVehicles vehicle)
    {
        Object someIrrelevantObject = vehicle.SomeValue;
        //here my change begins
        IPersonalVehicles personalVehicle = (IPersonalVehicles)vehicle;
        long somePersonalValue = personalVehicle.SomePersonalValue;
    }

}

public interface IVehicles

{
    Object SomeValue { get; }
}


public interface IPersonalVehicles

{
    long SomePersonalValue { get; }
}


public class Car : IVehicles, IPersonalVehicles
{
    public long SomePersonalValue => long.MinValue;

    public object SomeValue => "car value";
}

public class MotorBike : IVehicles, IPersonalVehicles
{
    public long SomePersonalValue => long.MaxValue;

    public object SomeValue => "motorbike value";
}
```

Comment: omg i am now checking I somehow lost interface implementation from my Car and Motorbike lol I will try to rebuild and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are using both interfaces, you could just inject `IPersonalVehicles` (which extend `IVehicles`). You aren't allowed to cast one interface in other because it doesn't make sense.

Try to think on this: `IPersonalVehicles` has its own properties (and methods) and same for `IVehicles`. So, how could you cast them? Remember that casting is based on inheritance

Let me know if I help you!